# iOS: show json info on detailView when click on annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a json file with some information I want to show this information on map, I can show Long and Lat on map, when you click on Annotation I have a button I want to show detail of my json on detail view, my problem is that I donot know how to show/send information on detail view based on annotation clicked,

Here is how I will load my detailViwe

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil 
bundle:nil];

    // my question is here In my detail view I have label like status, company, how to add json info here

    detail.status.text = ??!!!
    detail.company.text = ??!!!

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

In my Log I have the correct status printed but in my detail view controller I have null printed

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.status.text = _status.text;
    NSLog(@"Status %@ ",_status );
    NSLog(@"Status is %@ ",self.status.text);

}
```

Print is Status null
// // // Status is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access data from the `MKAnnotationView` provided in

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control`

The `view` object has an `annotation` property that will give you an object adopting the `MKAnnotation` protocol. This could be `MKPointAnnotation` as you already have, if just a `title` and `subtitle` will do. But you could also define a custom annotation class that holds onto a `status` and a `company`:

```
MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation; 
// annotation.status
// annotation.company
```

You'd have to create a `MyAnnotation` instance and insert the data in the place where you currently are creating `newAnnotation`.

As for once you have the data you need and you want to pass it to the DetailViewController, I suggest looking at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/2577986) or [Ole Begemann's tips here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/). In short, you can create a public property of your detail view controller, and then do something like:

```
    DetailViewController *destinationController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
    destinationController.name = annotation.status;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
```

In summary, your method could then look something like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation; 

    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil 
bundle:nil];

    detail.status = annotation.status;
    detail.company = annotation.company;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

And then set the `UILabel` texts in your detail view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.statusTextField.text = self.status;
    self.companyTextField.text = self.company;
}
```

**Update to clarify the creation of `MyAnnotation`:**

You always have the option of creating a custom class. Here could be an example for `MyAnnotation.h`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *status;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *company;

@end
```

Then in your map view controller import: `#import "MyAnnotation.h"`

and use `MyAnnotation` instead of `MKPointAnnotation`:

```
// create the annotation
newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
newAnnotation.title = dictionary[@"applicant"];
newAnnotation.subtitle = dictionary[@"company"];
newAnnotation.status = dictionary[@"status"];
newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];
newAnnotation.coordinate = location;  
[newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
```

Comment: thanks for reply, would you please write the complete answer, I mean for this custom part MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation; annotation.status ... based on my code, Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks again I have one more question, I add a label on my detail view and I try it with status but my label is null, do you know what is wrong here? I added edit part to my question

Comment: I'm not positive but I think your null label issue should be in a new SO question, otherwise this question starts to creep away from the original issue.